# multiple loops based on files in directories

Tags: shell, loops, terminal

I'm making a shell script that I need to make a loop. I have a directory called Files. Inside Files there are two folders. Each holding 500 files (folder1 and folder2). I need to get the filenames from both folder1 and folder2 because I need to concatenate the filename in folder1 with folder2. It needs to do this for every single file in there. So 250,000 times.

Anyone know how I would write that loop so that I can get all the names from both directories and loop correctly?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're in bash, then something like this

```
cd Files
for f1 in folder1/*
do
    for f2 in folder2/*
    do
        concat_name="${f1#*/}-${f2#*/}"
    done
done
```

Answer (score 0):

something like this should do, assuming that the two subdirectories are called `dir1` and `dir2`, this example only `echoes` the names naturally..

```
#!/bin/bash

for d1 in `ls Files/dir1`;
do
   for d2 in `ls Files/dir2`;
   do
      echo ${d1}_${d2}
   done
done
```

Comment: true :) i forgot the whitespace issue completely